# FS readFile ENOENT from blob or static file

Tags: meteor, fs

I am trying to readFile within my meteor application from an uploaded image on the client to the server. I am sending the blob to the server and then attempting to fs.readFile it on the server however I am getting the following error.

```
Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'blob....'
```

I also tested to make sure it wasn't just the blob by using static URLS and it also failed to find it. Producing the same error. I could be off on my understanding. My code is:

```
    fs.readFile(doc, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
       if (err) {
           console.log('Error: ' + err);
           return;
       }

       data = JSON.parse(data);
       console.log(data);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variable 'doc' is the blob itself, not a filename.

Have you already saved the file on the server? How did you get it there? With a Meteor.call?

Comment: I used a meteor call to send the blob so perhaps I did it wrong.

Comment: Passing the blob as a parameter to a Meteor.call is a very ineffecient way of transferring data, because it UUencodes the binary file, making it significantly bigger. I would recommend using vsivsi:file-collection